# c# unit test datetime against string

Tags: c#, datetime

I am doing a unit test for datetime and it fails because Test Name:

> GetDateTime2 Result Message:  Assert.AreEqual failed.
>   Expected:<28/05/2017 20:00:00 (System.String)>. Actual:<28/05/2017
>   20:00:00 (System.DateTime)>.

Is there any way of comparing the string against the datetime of do i have to change the properties of string date and string time?

```
public void GetDateTime()
{
      FootballEvent football = new FootballEvent();
      football.Time = "20:00:00";
      football.Date = "28/05/2017";
      var footballtime = football.GetDateTime();
      var expected = "28/05/2017 20:00:00";
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, footballtime);  
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just construct a `DateTime` to compare against? Why use a string representation at all?

Comment: Either convert the DateTime to a string, or convert the string to a DateTime...

Comment: consider comparing football.Hour == 20, football.Minute == 0, etc.  It can be useful to do something different in a unit test than the main code.  Tests are still clear and valuable but you may uncover something unexpected.  Probably not here but in your case that may be another way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 5):

as some people have stated within the comments why not just make a `DateTime` object then compare them?

**Example:**

```
var footballtime = football.GetDateTime();
var expected = "28/05/2017 20:00:00";
DateTime expectedDate = DateTime.Parse(expected);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedDate, footballtime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call `ToString()` with whatever format you want your time to be in for comparison.

```
var expected = "28/05/2017 20:00:00";
//Use HH for 00-23, use H for 0-23, use hh for 01-12 and use h for 1-12
Assert.AreEqual(expected, footballtime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

However it seems like you should be comparing both in the proper format (DateTime).

Ask yourself why you are initializing the times via string (`football.Time = "20:00:00";`), why not use the proper data type for Dates and Times (`DateTime`)

Comment: I tried that before but it didnt work i get back the correct answer.                                 Expected:<28/05/2017 20:00:00>. Actual:<28/05/2017 08:00:00>.